# Rewrite rule needed for various querystring combinations

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite a rule using htaccess, I currently have the following:

```
RewriteRule ^test/example/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/example\.html$ test/example/example/index.php?s=$1&t=$2&p=$3  [L]
```

which rewites the url from:

test/example/example/index.php?s=Red&t=Audi&p=Petrol

to

test/example/Red/Audi/Petrol/example.html

and this works but I would like the rule to work for the following 3 conditions:

1. where no values are in the querystring so just goes to the url: test/example/example.html
2. where "s" in the querystring has a value and then rewrite rule sends user to: test/example/Red/example.html

and

1. where all three vars have values and then the url goes to: test/example/Red/Audi/Petrol/example.html

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add three rewrite rules in this order:

```
RewriteRule ^test/example/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/example\.html$ test/example/example/index.php?s=Red&t=Audit&p=Petrol
RewriteRule ^test/example/(.*)/example\.html$ test/example/example.html?s=Red
RewriteRule ^test/example/example\.html$ test/example/example.html
```

And all done.

Comment: how do you have the patience for regex?  :P  very nice.

Comment: I write compilers for a living :) all regex are personal friends

Comment: Thanks, I should have guessed this! :)